Why does my JDBC URL spits out "Failed to parse the host:port pair"?
I have a pipeline that builds docker container from Github -> push to ECR -> pull from EC2 -> Run the docker container.
While the server runs ok when running in local, running the docker keeps failing in the EC2 server. The container should access RDS in private subnet and EC2 is in public subnet. I have opened up 3306 access but seems like it's not working.
What's the problem here?
Part of Github action: deploys.yml
      - name: Deploy to EC2 Instance
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v1.0.3
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ secrets.AWS_ECR_REPOSITORY }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_REGION_CODE: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION_CODE }}
          AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME }}
          DB_HOST: ${{ secrets.DB_HOST }}
          DB_PORT: ${{ secrets.DB_PORT }}
          DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
          DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
          DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
          JWT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}
          GOOGLE_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_EMAIL }}
          GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD }}
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.EC2_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.EC2_SSH_PORT }}
          envs: ECR_REGISTRY, ECR_REPOSITORY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_REGION_CODE, AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, JWT_SECRET, GOOGLE_EMAIL, GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD
          script: |
            sudo rm -rf .aws
            aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
            aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            aws configure set default.region $AWS_REGION_CODE
            aws configure set default.ouput json
            
            docker stop myapp || true
            docker rm myapp || true
            aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION_CODE | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_REGISTRY
            docker pull $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
            docker run -d --name myapp -p 8080:8080 $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest \
            -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
            -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY \
            -e AWS_REGION_CODE=$AWS_REGION_CODE \
            -e AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME=$AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME \
            -e DB_HOST=$DB_HOST \
            -e DB_PORT=$DB_PORT \
            -e DB_NAME=$DB_NAME \
            -e DB_USER=$DB_USER \
            -e DB_PASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD \
            -e JWT_SECRET=$JWT_SECRET \
            -e GOOGLE_EMAIL=$GOOGLE_EMAIL \
            -e GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD=$GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD \

application.yml
datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
    username: ${DB_USER}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}

Error log in docker logs myapp:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Failed to parse the host:port pair '${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}'.

